# play video from android internal storage

Tags: android, android-intent, video

I'm trying to play video files stored in android internal memory through intent. Files exist there but when i try to play them through intent, it give me the error "Media file not supported" or "can't play video" depending on device. I couldn't find where i'm wrong. here is my code

```
File mydir = activity.getDir("Videos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, filename);
String videoResource = fileWithinMyDir.getPath();
Uri intentUri = Uri.parse(videoResource);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(intentUri, "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

I don't know where i'm wrong and what should i do. any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: the video you are trying to play, try to play it directly from explorer to a media player, is it working or giving the same error.?

Comment: two reasons 1.out of buffer memory exception  and others is file type not supported.. see the logcat you will find the solution..

Comment: same video is playing from external storage. there is no issue with video. the only issue is how i can access it from internal storage.

Comment: i don't think we can access anything from internal storage???

Comment: @SarthakMittal am already playing audio files from internal storage :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you so much friends for participation, your efforts are very much appreciated. I'v found the solution of my problem. There is need to set file read true before playing it.

```
fileWithinMyDir.setReadable(true, false);
```

Now here is complete code of intent to play mp4 video from internal storage of android.

```
File mydir = activity.getDir("Videos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, headingsList.get(mPosition));
fileWithinMyDir.setReadable(true, false);
String videoResource = fileWithinMyDir.getPath();
Uri intentUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(videoResource));

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(intentUri, "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(String file_path));
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileUri.toString()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Then it is highly likely that you are not giving the path correctly :)

Comment: the path is right, video is there. I've checked it and also get file size, which is also right. if i save and play it from external storage, it worked but not from internal storage

Comment: What i remember is that android won't let you access internal folder programmatically

Comment: hahaha, that's good, then my knowledge ain't enough to answer your question. :)